How to pass environment variables for a AzureML pipeline job using python sdk v2?
I am following the example from this link: https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/jobs/pipelines/1a_pipeline_with_components_from_yaml/pipeline_with_components_from_yaml.ipynb
I am not sure how to pass the environment variables to the pipeline and use it inside the script that has the execution logic.

To pass environment variables in an Azure ML pipeline, you can define them in the component.yaml file under the environment section. Once the variables are defined, you can access the script using os module.
component.yaml:
environment:
- MY_ENV_VAR: value
scritp:
import os
my_var = os.getenv('MY_ENV_VAR')

No, the idea is to read from .env files and pass it as a variable to pipeline that can be used at run time and not to explicitly define it in a yaml file.
